# A question about bounding sentences

Tags: grammar

Here is the sentence:

'DCF analysis attempts to figure out the value of an investment **today, based** on projections of how much money it will generate in the future.'

I just don't understand why the second sentence is not started with '**is** based on ...'. I think the subject of the second sentence is 'DFC analysis', right? How is it bounded ? Please help me.

Comment: Why do you think there are two sentences?  There is only one period used as punctuation.

Comment: @Vegawatcher I'm assuming they mean "clauses"

Comment: "basted on projections..." is a [past participle clause](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/b1-b2-grammar/participle-clauses), a standard part of English grammar.

Answer (score -1):

There's only one sentence here. It's a complex one, though. Sentences are made up of clauses or phrases.

In this one sentence, the one main subject and verb are "DFC analysis attempts." The clause that starts with "based on" does contain a verb (or else it wouldn't be a clause); if you wanted, you could make a new sentence out of its parts: "*It will generate money.* The "it" is a pronoun that does not refer to DFC analysis, but to "an investment," so "an investment" is in some ways like the "subject" of that second clause.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence seems to mean: The DFC-type of analysis tries to figure out the value that an investment has today by basing its type of analysis on projections of how much money those investments will make in the future.

The word participle "based on" refers back to some sort of conclusion.

All the following sentences are variations on your sentence.  They all have the same meaning, but add or delete material.  Perhaps the variations will make the syntax clearer.

> The estimate of the value of an investment today is based on on how
> much money it will make in the future.  DFC analysis tries to do this
> by using projections.
>
> DFC analysis attempts to estimate a current investment value, and its
> estimate is based on the investment's projected value in the future.
>
> DFC analysis attempts to estimate a current investment value based on
> the investment's projected value in the future.

I personally would not have put a comma before "based on" because it is the essential point of the sentence and the phrase it introduces cannot be deleted without seriously changing the meaning.